# Error while trying to parse a html table using rvest html_table

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to read a table from this url:

https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/most_active_underlyings.htm

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/most_active_underlyings.htm"
tbl = read_html(url) %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table()
```

Error message:

```
Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the underlying data is available via a GET request at [this URL](https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/underlyings/ActiveUnderlyingsValue.json)

To get it into R... use this

```
library(jsonlite)
tmp <- fromJSON("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/underlyings/ActiveUnderlyingsValue.json")
df <- tmp$data

> head(df)
  FO_SYMBOL  VOLUME1   VOLUME2 TOTAL_VOLUME   VALUE1      VALUE2 TOTAL_VALUE UNDERLYINGVALUE
1 BANKNIFTY 1,36,046 83,23,989    84,60,035 8,521.68 5,23,514.39 5,32,036.07       31,160.35
2     NIFTY 1,01,176 41,10,138    42,11,314 9,050.23 3,69,056.93 3,78,107.16       11,856.80
3      SBIN   49,403    75,206     1,24,609 4,722.48    7,455.53   12,178.01          313.20
4  RELIANCE   15,093    30,744       45,837 1,183.71    2,459.68    3,643.39        1,564.90
5       TCS   20,578    40,737       61,315 1,044.29    2,139.57    3,183.86        2,016.25
6 ICICIBANK   21,264    19,857       41,121 1,548.93    1,462.62    3,011.55          529.75
        OP OPENINTEREST
1 1,824.84     7,75,725
2 1,349.93    15,54,357
3   143.40       69,024
4    27.77     1,29,759
5    26.17     1,00,669
6    23.59       99,142
```

Comment: the code was working until recently. Now I get this error: Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"

Comment: It looks like they've moved that to a different subdomain... Try this url instead: https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/underlyings/ActiveUnderlyingsValue.json

Comment: Just use `www1` instead of `www` in the domain.

Comment: I was able to discover this by using the network monitor in firefox by pressing `F12`. Chrome has a similar utility. Go to the original site, press F12, reload the site to regenerate the traffic and look at the GET requests. You should see this one in there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor